# How do I read a URL in XSL-T then pass it into a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

Apologies in advance on this: I'm new to XSLT and jQuery, as will become obvious very soon. First I'll give the (stripped-down) contents of the files I'm using, then I'll pose my questions.

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contentDefinition>
  <contentDefinitionNode objectId="rssFeedUrl" type="textbox" label="RSS Feed URL" required="yes" translate="false">http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rss.xml</contentDefinitionNode>  
</contentDefinition>
```

test.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="rssFeedUrl" select="//contentDefinitionNode[@objectId='rssFeedUrl']/@select" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ContentDemo\scripts\jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#test').rssfeed('$rssFeedUrl', {
          });
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'd like to do is read the rssFeedUrl from test.xml and pass it into test.xsl's rssfeed function. Running the transform in VS, I keep getting the following message: "The specified URL is invalid." I know the URL is okay, as when I pass it directly into the rssfeed function I get the feed I'm expecting. So I'm guessing it's being read from the xml file incorrectly.

I did try for quite a while to troubleshoot this myself but can't even figure out how to display what the invalid URL is. I tried inserting the following into the  element but receive an error stating the variable is invalid:

```
<script>
  function showIt() {
   alert($rssFeedUrl)
  };
  window.onload=showIt
</script>
```

I'm guessing this error is because the variable is out of scope, but I'm not sure how to fix it. This is just a long way of saying I attempted to debug the URL problem, but am not sure how to even go about doing it. (I can't even figure out how to use xsl to print out the value of the  to the screen.)

I'd appreciate any help. Again, I apologize if the answers to these questions are obvious. I'm pretty new to most of this.

Comment: Are you getting the error while running XSL transformation? If yes, I cannot reproduce the problem using the code you have posted - see: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEY.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes, that's where I was getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this, but I got something working right after I posted the question. I updated the function call to look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('<xsl:value-of select="contentDefinition/contentDefinitionNode    [@objectId= 'rssFeedUrl']"/>', {
    limit:<xsl:value-of select="contentDefinition/contentDefinitionNode [@objectId= 'rssItemMaxCount']"/>
    });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is the most robust or slickest way, but it's working as I'd hoped.

Comment: What you have to understand here is that the XSLT transformation does not happen at the same time as the JQuery is executed.  When you run the XSLT transformation, it takes your input XML, and outputs (in this case) HTML.
After that is complete the HTML can be displayed, at which point the JQuery is executed.

Your solution works because it inserts the values from the source XML into the document before the JQuery runs, so when the JQuery runs, it already has the values of the data to work with.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: Thanks for the information. The order of execution was one of many things in the scenario I wasn't clear on.